# How to make a specific element to have an active class using v-if and v-bind

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is the following code:

```
<div class="filter-item-wrapper-inner">
                <div class="filter-item" @click="filterImages(1)">
                    <div class="bg-item-img"></div>
                    <div class="filter-item-overlay active">
                        <h5>{{webData.filters[0]}}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="filter-item" @click="filterImages(2)">
                    <div class="bg-item-img"></div>
                    <div class="filter-item-overlay">
                        <h5>{{webData.filters[1]}}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="filter-item" @click="filterImages(3)">
                    <div class="bg-item-img"></div>
                    <div class="filter-item-overlay">
                        <h5>{{webData.filters[2]}}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="filter-item" @click="filterImages(4)">
                    <div class="bg-item-img"></div>
                    <div class="filter-item-overlay">
                        <h5>{{webData.filters[3]}}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="filter-item" @click="filterImages(5)">
                    <div class="bg-item-img"></div>
                    <div class="filter-item-overlay">
                        <h5>{{webData.filters[4]}}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="filter-item" @click="filterImages(6)">
                    <div class="bg-item-img"></div>
                    <div class="filter-item-overlay">
                        <h5 class="entertainment-font">{{webData.filters[5]}}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="filter-item" @click="filterImages(7)">
                    <div class="bg-item-img"></div>
                    <div class="filter-item-overlay">
                        <h5>{{webData.filters[6]}}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the class:

```
.filter-item .filter-item-overlay.active {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7291);
}
```

So I want to make single selected element to set as active by click. So when the user clicks on specific filter it remains active. Is there some alternative with using v-bind and v-if?

Comment: You could use style binding. For details take a look at the vue docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: @diealtebremse could you write an example as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your code using style binding:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    activeIndex: 0
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li @click="activeIndex=1" :class="[activeIndex===1 ? 'active' : '']">One</li>
    <li @click="activeIndex=2" :class="[activeIndex===2 ? 'active' : '']">Two</li>
    <li @click="activeIndex=3" :class="[activeIndex===3 ? 'active' : '']">Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you above, you should take a look at the vue doc : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

But this might help you :

```
<template>


<div
    v-for="i in 7"
    :key="'img_' + i"
    class="filter-item" 
    @click="filterImages(i)"
  >
    <div class="bg-item-img"></div>
    <div 
      class="filter-item-overlay"
      :class="{'active' : filteredImage === i}"
    >
      <h5>{{webData.filters[i]}}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Filter",
  data() {
    return {
      filteredImage: -1,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filterImages(index) {
      this.filteredImage = index;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```